# MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException thrown when unplugging / replugging a smartcard with embedded authentication certificate for TLS connection

Tags: c#, tls1.2, smartcard, mailkit

I'm getting a MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException while trying to connect to an email server using Mailkit. The authentication is based on TLS 1.2 and uses a certificate that is embedded in a smartcard.

I can connect and get some email folders as long as the card remains in the reader. But if I unplug and replug it without restarting the application, the exception is thrown.

I've written a simple test console app to test a connection / get email folders / disconnection sequence using the IMAP protocol.

```
using Agm.Commun.MSS;
using Agm.Commun.Utils.Certificates;
using MailKit;
using System;

namespace Agm.Commun.TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        const string IMAP_HOST = "frontimap-igcsante.formation.mssante.fr"; // This is a test server
        const int IMAP_PORT = 143;
        const string userEMailAdress = "foo0@pro.formation.mssante.fr"; // This is a fake email address

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Simple console test app");

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Plug a smartcard into the reader then press [Enter]. [Q]+[Enter] to quit");
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (input.ToLower() == "q")
                    break;

                MssManagerBis mssManager = ConfigureMssManager();

                var emailFolders = mssManager.GetFolders();

                Console.WriteLine("Email Folders for " + userEMailAdress);
                foreach (IMailFolder folder in emailFolders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(folder.FullName);
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            } while (true);
        }

        private static MssManagerBis ConfigureMssManager()
        {
            CertificateManager certificateManager = new CertificateManager(Utils.Certificates.CertificateType.CPS);
            MssManagerBis mssManager = new MssManagerBis(certificateManager.AuthenticationCertificate, userEMailAdress, IMAP_HOST, IMAP_PORT);

            return mssManager;
        }
    }
}
```

The CertificateManager gets the certificate from the CurrentUser/Personal Windows certificate store. This certificate is automatically added to the store when the smartcard is inserted into the reader and is removed from the store when the smartcard is unplugged.

Here is the class that manages the IMAP connection / get folders / disconnection sequence :

```
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Net.Imap;
using MailKit.Security;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;

namespace Agm.Commun.MSS
{
    public class MssManagerBis
    {
        #region Properties
        private X509Certificate2 AuthenticationCertificate;
        private string Email;
        private string HostImap;
        private int PortImap;

        // Allowed cipher suites to be used with TLS 1.2 connections
        private static readonly string[] CIPHERSUITEALLOWED = {
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
            "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
        };
        #endregion

        public MssManagerBis(X509Certificate2 pCertificate, string pEmail, string pHostImap, int pPortImap)
        {
            AuthenticationCertificate = pCertificate;
            Email = pEmail;
            HostImap = pHostImap;
            PortImap = pPortImap;
        }

        public ImapClient ImapConnect()
        {
            ImapClient imapClient = new ImapClient();

            // set authentication certificate that is embedded in the smartcard
            imapClient.ClientCertificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
            imapClient.ClientCertificates.Add(AuthenticationCertificate);

            // Set configuration to check certificate revocation 
            imapClient.CheckCertificateRevocation = true;

            // TLS 1.2 required by the email server
            imapClient.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

            // Add handler to callback method for validation
            imapClient.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateValidationCallBack;

            // Actual connection to the email server - Fails on second attempt after the same smartcard was unplugged / replugged
            imapClient.Connect(HostImap, PortImap, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);

            // Use a cipher that is compatible with the email server
            string cipherAlgorithmUsed = GetCipherSuite(imapClient);
            if (CIPHERSUITEALLOWED.Contains(cipherAlgorithmUsed))
            {
                // Authenticate user 
                imapClient.Authenticate(Email, "");

                return imapClient;
            }
            else
            {
                IMAPDisconnect(imapClient);
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Cipher suite {0} not supported, IMAP connexion cancelled.", cipherAlgorithmUsed));
            }
        }

        public IList<IMailFolder> GetFolders()
        {
            IList<IMailFolder> folders = new List<IMailFolder>();

            ImapClient imapClient = ImapConnect();

            if (imapClient == null)
                return folders;

            foreach (FolderNamespace ns in imapClient.PersonalNamespaces)
            {
                folders = imapClient.GetFolders(ns);
            }

            IMAPDisconnect(imapClient);

            return folders;
        }

        public void IMAPDisconnect(ImapClient imapClient)
        {
            if (imapClient != null && imapClient.IsConnected)
            {
                imapClient.Disconnect(true);
                imapClient.ClientCertificates.Clear();
                imapClient.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private bool CertificateValidationCallBack(object pSender, X509Certificate pCertificate, X509Chain pChain, SslPolicyErrors pSslPolicyErrors)
        {

            // Vérification de la validité de la période de validité du certificat
            if (pCertificate is X509Certificate2 certificate2)
            {

                if (certificate2.NotBefore > DateTime.Now || certificate2.NotAfter < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Le certificat n'est pas valide à cette date.");
                }
            }

            // Vérification de l'identité de l'émetteur du certificat
            if (pChain.ChainElements.Count > 1)
            {
                if (pCertificate.Issuer != pChain.ChainElements[1].Certificate.Subject)
                {
                    throw new Exception("L'émetteur du certificat n'a pas pu être vérifié.");
                }
            }

            // Vérification de la chaîne de certificats
            pChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
            pChain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
            pChain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(1000);
            pChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.AllowUnknownCertificateAuthority | X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreCertificateAuthorityRevocationUnknown | X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreEndRevocationUnknown;
            pChain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = DateTime.Now;

            bool isChainValid = pChain.Build((X509Certificate2)pCertificate);
            if (!isChainValid)
            {
                throw new Exception("La chaîne de certificats n'a pas pu être vérifiée.");
            }

            return true;
        }

        private string GetCipherSuite(ImapClient imapClient)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            if (imapClient.SslProtocol == SslProtocols.Tls12)
                stringBuilder.Append("TLS_");

            if ((int)imapClient.SslKeyExchangeAlgorithm == 44550)
                stringBuilder.Append("ECDHE_RSA_WITH_");

            switch (imapClient.SslCipherAlgorithm)
            {
                case CipherAlgorithmType.Aes256:
                    stringBuilder.Append("AES_256_");
                    break;
                case CipherAlgorithmType.Aes128:
                    stringBuilder.Append("AES_128_");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (imapClient.SslProtocol == SslProtocols.Tls12)
                stringBuilder.Append("GCM_");

            stringBuilder.Append(imapClient.SslHashAlgorithm.ToString().ToUpper());

            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }        
    }
}
```

The first time the connection is opened, there is no problem : The connection is opened and the GetFolders() method returns a list of folders. I can do it an infinite number of times as long as I do not remove the smartcard from the reader. If I remove it and then put it back into the reader, the SslHandshakeException is thrown.
I've tried different connection modes (SecureSocketOptions.Auto, SecureSocketOptions.StartTlsWhenAvailable), with or without the certificationValidationCallbak (as it could not release some resources if not removed properly). I also waited up to 10 minutes between 2 attempts.

Note that this is a secured email server that only accepts Tls 1.2 (and above) and specific cipher suites. Only smartcard certificates can be used to securely open connections.

I'm using .NET core 2.2 but I do not think it matters that much. I could probably move to a more recent framework if that could work better.

I'm guessing the Windows PC/SC layer keeps some kind of cache related to the smartcard because if I try a different card for the second attempt, it will work. But as soon as I try the same one again, the exception is raised. Is there a way to force cleaning or refreshing such a cache?

The certificate is retrieved using the following method :

```
private List<X509Certificate2> GetAuthenticationCertificateList(CertificateType certificateType)
{
    StoreLocation certificatelocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;

    List<X509Certificate2> certificateList;
    using (X509Store x509Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, certificatelocation))
    {
        x509Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        certificateList = x509Store.Certificates.OfType<X509Certificate2>()
            .Where(certificate => certificate.Extensions.OfType<X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension>()
            .Any(extension => extension.EnhancedKeyUsages.OfType<Oid>()
            .Any(usage => usage.Value == ExternalOids.OID_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION))).ToList();

        // Pour les authentifications avec carte, il faut aussi vérifier le rôle de type "smart card".
        if (certificateType == CertificateType.CPS || certificateType == CertificateType.CPE)
        {
            certificateList = certificateList
                .Where(certificate => certificate.Extensions.OfType<X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension>()
                .Any(extension => extension.EnhancedKeyUsages.OfType<Oid>()
                .Any(usage => usage.Value == ExternalOids.OID_SMART_CARD_LOGON)))
                .ToList();
         }
    }

    return certificateList;
}
```

Maybe the certificate should be retrieved differently, i.e. via the PKCS11 library instead?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: I have no idea if this will work or not because I don't have any smartcards or any mail servers that accept client-side SSL certificates, but maybe you can try: `var certificate = new X509Certificate2(actualCertificate.RawData)` so that the certificate is loaded from memory rather than the file system/cache?

Comment: @jstedfast Thanks for your suggestion. I tried it, but the behavior remained the same : The connection is successful until the card is plugged-out / replugged-in.

Comment: Darn, was hoping that would work for you.